# Where was dropped the draggable element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following `draggable` call, using [jqueryui](/questions/tagged/jqueryui):

```
$someElm.draggable({     
    helper: "clone",         
    stop: function (ev, ui) {
        /* where was this dropped? */            
    }                        
});
```

On stop handler, I need the drop target. I don't use droppable, but only draggable.

So, how can I get the drop target?

`ev.target` seems to be the dragged element.

---

By *target* I mean the top element where the draggable was dropped (drag stop). This can be different than `ev.target.parent()`.

Make an association with click handlers:

```
div.foo > div.bar
```

Listening for clicks on `div.foo` will catch the clicks on `div.bar`, but `ev.target` will be `div.bar` if the click was done on `div.bar` element (otherwise it will be `div.foo`).

Comment: @Anton That's the parent of the dragged element, but the dropped area may be another element.

Comment: Cannot you use a common class for all droppable elements and then use `$(ev.target).closest('.droppable')` e.g?

Comment: @A.Wolff I could, but `ev.target` is not on the elements are on different levels.

Comment: You should provide a jsFiddle which replicates your issue

Comment: Perhaps you should use the `droppable` widget? (http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/)

Comment: @LeeTaylor I don't need droppable. See my workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ui` variable contains the `offset` property (with `left` and `top` values).

Using `document.elementFromPoint` function we can get the element on that position that is exactly the element where the element was dropped:

```
$someElm.draggable({     
    helper: "clone",         
    stop: function (ev, ui) {
       var dropTarget = $(document.elementFromPoint(ui.offset.left, ui.offset.top));
    }                        
});
```

Even it looks like a hack, it seems it's the only way to do this (if there are better alternative post answers/comments).

> ### [`Document.elementFromPoint(x, y)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.elementFromPoint)
>
> `x` and `y` specify the coordinates to check, in CSS pixels relative to the upper-left corner of the document's containing window or frame.
>
> Returns the element from the document whose elementFromPoint method is being called which is the topmost element which lies under the given point.  To get an element, specify the point via coordinates, in CSS pixels, relative to the upper-left-most point in the window or frame containing the document.